# Formatting a 3TB harddisk to NTFS

Tags: format

I've just installed a new harddisk in my desktop for data storage, I want to format it with NTFS*. I first tried `disk utility` and `gparted` to format the volume, but using both I get:

> "Filesystem not clean"

and

> "Device is mounted and no online capability in fsck tool for file system"

How can I create a 3TB NTFS partition?

** I want it to be usable across multiple platforms in the future, so this seems sensible, but perhaps it is not the best choice*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gparted partition editor, asks you to select a partition table, (importantly!) don't use the default when it shows an WARNING message, select `Advanced` and choose [`GPT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (rather than the default MSDOS).

The MSDOS partition table has a maximum partition length (2.2TB):

> Create Primary Partition #1 (ntfs, 2.73 TiB) on /dev/sdd  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
>
> create empty partition  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
>   libparted messages    ( INFO )
>
> partition length of 5860530176 sectors exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295

The GPT's maximum is [9.4ZB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), since this is larger than 3TB you should no longer get this error.